# mod_rewrite: Error whilst rewriting subdomain to directory via %{HTTP_HOST}

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain

## Problems with `mod_rewrite`

I am having more trouble than I thought when it comes to Apache's `mod_rewrite`. I've already posted one question on the
matter, and that has been clarified, but I continue to get errors where I cannot see any logical fault in the
configuration. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

The `.htaccess` I am using is the following:

```
# Begin Rewrite Module for http://*.example.com/
# ==============================================
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    # Turn the rewrite engine on and set the base path.
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    # Map subdomains to their respective directories.
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+)\.example\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public_subdomains/%1/$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

This doesn't work because of too many internal redirects, resulting in a `500 Internal Server Error` - here is the debug log for it:

```
[Fri Feb 15 16:49:30.318509 2013] [core:error] [pid 2316:tid 1708] [client 127.0.0.1:9141] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
[Fri Feb 15 16:49:30.318509 2013] [core:debug] [pid 2316:tid 1708] core.c(3502): [client 127.0.0.1:9141] AH00121: r->uri = /public_subdomains/sub1/public_subdomains/sub1/public_subdomains/sub1/public_subdomains/sub1/public_subdomains/sub1/public_subdomains/sub1/public_subdomains/sub1/public_subdomains/sub1/public_subdomains/sub1/public_subdomains/sub1/index.php
[Fri Feb 15 16:49:30.318509 2013] [core:debug] [pid 2316:tid 1708] core.c(3508): [client 127.0.0.1:9141] AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /public_subdomains/sub1/public_subdomains/sub1/public_subdomains/sub1/public_subdomains/sub1/public_subdomains/sub1/public_subdomains/sub1/public_subdomains/sub1/public_subdomains/sub1/public_subdomains/sub1/index.php
[Fri Feb 15 16:49:30.318509 2013] [core:debug] [pid 2316:tid 1708] core.c(3508): [client 127.0.0.1:9141] AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /public_subdomains/sub1/public_subdomains/sub1/public_subdomains/sub1/public_subdomains/sub1/public_subdomains/sub1/public_subdomains/sub1/public_subdomains/sub1/public_subdomains/sub1/index.php
[Fri Feb 15 16:49:30.318509 2013] [core:debug] [pid 2316:tid 1708] core.c(3508): [client 127.0.0.1:9141] AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /public_subdomains/sub1/public_subdomains/sub1/public_subdomains/sub1/public_subdomains/sub1/public_subdomains/sub1/public_subdomains/sub1/public_subdomains/sub1/index.php
[Fri Feb 15 16:49:30.318509 2013] [core:debug] [pid 2316:tid 1708] core.c(3508): [client 127.0.0.1:9141] AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /public_subdomains/sub1/public_subdomains/sub1/public_subdomains/sub1/public_subdomains/sub1/public_subdomains/sub1/public_subdomains/sub1/index.php
[Fri Feb 15 16:49:30.318509 2013] [core:debug] [pid 2316:tid 1708] core.c(3508): [client 127.0.0.1:9141] AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /public_subdomains/sub1/public_subdomains/sub1/public_subdomains/sub1/public_subdomains/sub1/public_subdomains/sub1/index.php
[Fri Feb 15 16:49:30.318509 2013] [core:debug] [pid 2316:tid 1708] core.c(3508): [client 127.0.0.1:9141] AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /public_subdomains/sub1/public_subdomains/sub1/public_subdomains/sub1/public_subdomains/sub1/index.php
[Fri Feb 15 16:49:30.318509 2013] [core:debug] [pid 2316:tid 1708] core.c(3508): [client 127.0.0.1:9141] AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /public_subdomains/sub1/public_subdomains/sub1/public_subdomains/sub1/index.php
[Fri Feb 15 16:49:30.318509 2013] [core:debug] [pid 2316:tid 1708] core.c(3508): [client 127.0.0.1:9141] AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /public_subdomains/sub1/public_subdomains/sub1/index.php
[Fri Feb 15 16:49:30.318509 2013] [core:debug] [pid 2316:tid 1708] core.c(3508): [client 127.0.0.1:9141] AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /public_subdomains/sub1/index.php
[Fri Feb 15 16:49:30.318509 2013] [core:debug] [pid 2316:tid 1708] core.c(3508): [client 127.0.0.1:9141] AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /
```

I found a sort-of solution for it, by replacing the `[L]` flag for the `[END]` flag on the RewriteRule, and it works perfectly mapping the request URI exactly to the corresponding file in the sub-domain directory.

Unfortunately it works too perfectly. A call to `subdomain.example.com/folder/` interally rewrites to `example.com/public_subdomains/subdomain/folder/` without taking into account the DirectoryIndex, when it should rewrite as `example.com/public_subdomains/subdomain/folder/index.php` (assuming that `index.php` is set as the DirectoryIndex).

If anyone can help me shed light on this, I would be eternally grateful!

Comment: I think you are mixing URLs with system paths. This `http://example.com/index.php` and this `/public_html/index.php` point to the same file. In .htaccess files the [PT](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_pt) flag is implied and only URLs should be used. Maybe there are other issues in your question, but this one is pretty evident.

Comment: I've edited the question to remove the `/public_html` from the list of example rewrites, but no, system paths are not used. All the paths are relative to the document root (that was a problem I fixed from an earlier question). But kudos for pointing out the difference between system paths and URLs - I spent days trying to understand that problem!

Comment: Have you tried RewriteLog with at least RewrteLogLevel 3? This can help you debugging. I thing, there can be problem with: `RewriteRule (.*) public_subdomains/%1/$1 [L]` But RewriteLog tells you more.

Comment: Pls clarify whether you want redirected URI as `http://example.com/public_subdomains/subdomain/folder/index.php` or `http://subdomain.example.com/public_subdomains/subdomain/folder/index.php` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, there is a logic error all right. Let me refer you to the wonderful control flow diagram from the [docs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rO3E.png):

[image: Control flow diagram about the workings of mod_rewrite]

You see, an internal redirect is a request too, so it's once again processed by any and all rewrite rules. So, suppose a user requests something.example.com/x: RewriteRule macthes, RewriteCond is fulfilled, so an internal redirect to public_subdomains/something/x is made. The new request is to something.example.com/public_subdomains/something/x: RewriteRule matches, RewriteCond is fulfilled... And there you have the endless loop.

The [L] flag only stops processing of the current request: the request will be processed in the second pass anyway. The [END] flag does stop the loop, but it's a brute-force thing, as you've noticed it has side effects, so it'd be better to incorporate a condition that stops the recursion. Something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+)\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public_subdomains/%1
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public_subdomains/%1/$1 [L]
```

The added RewriteCond would check to see if the requested uri already begins with "public_subdomains/something".

It's untested, so may have issues, but this is the basic idea.

Comment: I find adding `RewriteRule ^public_subdomains - [L]` before the rewrite rule is cleaner than adding another `RewriteCond`.

Comment: @mootinator Absolutely, that looks a lot more idiomatic and nicer.

Comment: Although it didn't provide a solution (finally got round it by getting access to the DNS records), your answer deserves the bounty - well written explanation that will help me in the future I'm sure.