# How can I "close" a website on Sundays only

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I am looking for a script that redirects all pages of a website to a page stating that the whole site is closed on Sundays for religious reasons.

It should redirect only on Sunday. On all other days of the week the site should function as normal.

I'd like to do that at the server level in a `.htaccess` file, or in a PHP script.

I could imagine something like this:

```
$day = date('w');
if ($day == 0) { // Sunday...
    header("Location: http://www.domain.com/closedonsunday.html");
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use the following rule in `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on

#--if WDAY ==0--#
RewriteCond %{TIME_WDAY} 0

#--redirect the domain to /closedonsunday.html--#
RewriteRule ^((?!closedonsunday\.html).*)$ /closedonsunday.html [L,R]
```

The `%{TIME_WDAY}` variable represents the day of the week (0-6).

The code above will redirect all requests to `/closedonsunday.html` if the condition is met.

Comment: It works! Yet only for the homepage not for all pages in one. May I ask your guidance here?

Comment: @Anthony tweak the matcher regex in the rewriteRule so that it suits your needs. Read up on the syntax in the [docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) (but it's basically just pcre)

Comment: @SáT So I did the las few hours. The 'best' result is getting 500 internal server errors like ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Also code like

Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/closedonsunday$
RewriteRule $ /closedonsunday.html [R=302,L]

doesn't seem to work in my situation.

Comment: @Anthony You can check your server logs to see more details about the errors. Also, read up on how mod_rewrite's working, how redirects are performed. The [Sacred Flowchart](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14900458/477453) helped me a lot in understanding this beast.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The flowchart is perfect!

Answer (score 1):

You can get numeric representation of the day of the week with `date()` and to redirect:

```
$day = date('N'); //1 (for Monday) through 7 (for Sunday)
if($day == 7){
    header("Location: sunday_page.php");
}
```

It's quite good to do it via PHP by puting this code on very top of your header.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't do this with `header` since users, depending on their browser settings, *might* get a cached copy of the page on days other than Monday.

You can use `include` to execute script from another file. At the top of each page add the following:

```
include 'path/to/closedonsunday.php';
```

And then `closedonsunday.php` would have a very simple check like:

```
if (date('w') == 0) {
    /* ... message here ... */
    exit;
}
```

The `exit` is the vital part here as as it will stop PHP dead.

You should also be careful with timezones.  Ensure that your server clock is set correctly and that your script knows which timezone it should use!

Comment: Hi,

Thanks a bunch, especially on the cached copy and server clock setting.

I guess putting the include on the top of each page is quite a thing for a webshop with over 1.000 pages.

Is there a single page solution as far as you are concerned?

Comment: It depends on your application design.  I tend to always have a single `include` statement on each page so that things like authentication and database connections can be handled in only one place (this would be a 'single page solution').  If you have >1,000 pages that don't currently `include` anything then there's a lot of work to modify them all. In that case the `.htaccess` approach in another answer here would be less work.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, You should use **.htaccess** file. Date and time values in **.htaccess** come in the form

> %{TIME_XXXX}

where **XXXX** is the type of date or time you want.

In case if you want to redirect a generic url to one which contains today’s date, you might use:

> RewriteRule ^posts/today$ /posts/%{TIME_YEAR}-%{TIME_MON}-%{TIME_DAY}

That would result in /posts/today being redirected to something like /posts/2015-08-27

If you wanted redirect a page after a date (and time) is password you could use something like the following, where if the date is passed 9am on 27th August 2015 the redirect will happen. We use a simple number comparison of turning the date into an integer and then comparing it.

```
RewriteCond %{TIME_YEAR}%{TIME_MON}%{TIME_DAY}%{TIME_HOUR} >2015082709
RewriteRule ^$ /destination/url.html [R=301,L]
```

In your case

```
RewriteCond %{TIME_WDAY} = 0 // condition
RewriteRule URL on which you wants to redirect
```

For more tutorial you can use the link [Tutorial](http://harrybailey.com/2015/08/htaccess-redirects-based-on-date-and-time/) and
[link 2](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/time_hour-rewritecond-time.html#time-wday)

If you wants to use PHP way then use the switch. If later you wants to redirect on any other day too then you can manage that here.

```
$day = date('N'); //1 for Monday , 2 for Tuesday ... 7 For Sunday
//N is  The ISO-8601 numeric representation of a day
switch($day){
case 1:
  header('location: site for Monday');break;
case 2:
  header('location: site link for Tuesday'); break;
}
 . 
 .
case 7: 
 header("Location: http://www.domain.com/closedonsunday.html"); break;
default:
    code to be executed if day is different from all labels; // it is not possible in this case :)
```

}

Comment: Thanks for your htaccess tutorial. 

Am I right that redirecting the site every sunday it come to this:

RewriteCond %{TIME_DAY} = 0
RewriteRule ^$ /destination/url.html [R=301,L]

Comment: No TIME_DAY represents current date. you should TIME_WDAY
current week-day (0-6).

Comment: you can also use switch case. Switch is always better than If else conditions.

Comment: Please feel free to ask if you are not able to solve your problem.